# Как добавить столбец вида TIMESTAMP заданного формата

Tags: sql, oracle

Как в таблицу `ORDERS` добавить столбец `ORDERDATE` с заданным форматированием?
Либо как сменить формат у уже существуещего столбца?

```
alter TABLE ORDERS ADD ORDERDATE TIMESTAMP 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle хранит данные в БД в бинарном виде, поэтому когда речь заходит о форматировании DATE/TIMESTAMP подразумевается ввод и вывод - т.е. как показывать данные при выводе (SELECT) и как их парсить при вводе (INSERT / UPDATE).

Обычно это делается на стороне клиента:

для типа DATE:

```
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT="YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS";
```

для типа TIMESTAMP:

```
alter session set NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT="YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS";
```

для типа TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE:

```
alter session set NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT="YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS";
```

PS очень советую задуматься об использовании `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` - это поможет избежать многих проблем, особенно если данные будут храниться для/из нескольких различных временных поясов.

---

Также можно управлять настройками по умолчанию при помощи *переменной окружения ОС* - `NLS_TERRITORY` - формат даты будет установлен в наиболее распространенный для данной страны.

Comment: те  сначала создаю столбец: alter TABLE ORDERS ADD ORDERDATE TIMESTAMP(0), а потом уже меняю его формат?

Comment: @Vladimir, немного расширил ответ...